# Can you insert a value from a range in mysql?

Tags: mysql, table

So basically I have one auto incrementing column which is increments every time a ticket has been sold. However I also have 50 chairs inside the room. since I can't use auto_increment 2 times is there another way to select one of the 50 chairs. basically something like

```
mysql_query(INSERT INTO table (`chair`) VALUE (Range(1, 50) as long as picked number not taken))
```

Comment: Unclear. Try to show on a sample data (not 50, 5-10 enough).

Comment: *select one of the 50 chairs* `1+49*RAND()`

Comment: @Akina - that never quite reaches 50.  And you probably want an integer.  Consider `FLOOR(50*RAND()) + 1`.